# Generate RSA key with large public exponent

Tags: go, encryption, cryptography, rsa

**Step 1.** I  generated RSA key pairs for Alice and Bob, respectively, and encrypted a message for Alice using Alice's public key.

**Step 2.** I multiplied the public exponent of Bob's public key with the private exponent of Alice's private key to have a new number.

**Step 3.** I generated a new RSA public key by `keyRegen := rsa.PublicKey{N: keyPubAliceN, E: ENew}` and used it to encrypt the message encrypted in step 1.

**Step 4.** I decrypted the re-encrypted message from step 3 using Bob's private key. Theoretical now Bob can get the original message, which is the expected output.

**Problem:** However, I found that the public exponent in [rsa.PublicKey](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/rsa#PublicKey) should be an `int`, while my new public exponent generated in step 2 is a `big.Int`. I converted it into `int` and used the newly generated public key to do the encryption but error `panic: crypto/rsa: public exponent too small` happened. Also I guess I should not do such a conversion because the new number is probably larger than `int` range. Then are there any ways to generate a new RSA key with the large public exponent? Thank you!

**Codes:**

```
package main
import (
        "crypto"
        "crypto/rand"
        "crypto/rsa"
        "crypto/sha256"
        "fmt"
        "math/big"
    )
    
func main() {
    keyPriAlice, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 1024)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    keyPubAlice := keyPriAlice.PublicKey
    keyPriAliceD := keyPriAlice.D
    keyPubAliceN := keyPubAlice.N

    keyPriBob, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 1024)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    keyPubBob := keyPriBob.PublicKey
    keyPubBobE := big.NewInt(int64(keyPubBob.E))
    
    message := "secret"
    encryptedBytes, err := rsa.EncryptOAEP(
        sha256.New(),
        rand.Reader,
        &keyPubAlice,
        []byte(message),
        nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    z := new(big.Int)
    y := z.Mul(keyPriAliceD, keyPubBobE)
    ENew := int(y.Int64())
    keyRegen := rsa.PublicKey{N: keyPubAliceN, E: ENew}
    
    reEncryptedBytes, err := rsa.EncryptOAEP(
        sha256.New(),
        rand.Reader,
        &keyRegen,
        []byte(encryptedBytes),
        nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    // decrypt the re-encrypted plaintext using Bob's private key
    decryptedBytes, err := keyPriBob.Decrypt(nil, reEncryptedBytes, &rsa.OAEPOptions{Hash: crypto.SHA256})
    fmt.Println("decryptedBytes:", decryptedBytes)
    }
```

Comment: Note that many applications do not consider public exponents larger than 32 bits, as you found out. The only way around this may be to use another library, change the library implementation or perform special tricks like using private key encryption using a public key (for which the results may vary, as the RSA OAEP padding operation may be impeded).

Comment: Thanks @MaartenBodewes. What do you mean by "perform special tricks like using private key encryption using a public key (for which the results may vary, as the RSA OAEP padding operation may be impeded)"?

Comment: Well in principle a private key consists of an exponent and a modulus, although quite often the elements required to perform the Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT) are present as well. So you can create a "private key" from a public key and then do the calculations. The problem is that the library may treat the operations differently for public & private keys, so there is a large chance that this may not work. It might however be less work than using another RSA library entirely.

Comment: If you try to encrypt with Alice's n and decrypt with Bob's (different) n it will never work -- even if you find code to handle the larger-than-usual numbers correctly.

Comment: That's right @dave_thompson_085. Thanks for your reminder. I found this when I revisited RSA formulas. It can work only if Alice's and Bob's n are the same, which means the Euler totient function of n are the same. In this case Alice can know Bob's private key, which is fine in my case. The bad thing is that Bob can deduce Alice's private key. But I am just wondering it maybe difficult as it is to deduce m from ed mod m = 1 where e and d are Bob's keys and are very large numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably need to use a different library for this.  In most modern RSA contexts, we want d, the private exponent, to be large for security reasons, but we want e to be small for performance reasons.  As a practical matter, the vast majority of secure implementations I've seen choose 65537 for e, which is secure and fast (due to containing exactly two ones).

The Go library has made the assumption, based on the fact that practically every real-world scenario that isn't an exploit wants a small e, that e will fit into an int, which may have been improvident, but is ultimately reasonable.  You may find that OpenSSL is more suitable for this purpose, since it tends to make fewer assumptions about the data passed to it.

Comment: To prevent denial-of-service attacks, OpenSSL does limit pubexp size _if_ the modulus is (also) 'large'. See https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/include/openssl/rsa.h#L51 .